# Как работает CSS grid-autoflow?

Tags: css, css3, css-grid

Столкнулся с проблемой того, что не понимаю как работают "неявные гриды". Документацию читал, читал MDN, еще пару ресурсов. Остался открытый вопрос.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(2, 100px) / repeat(6, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.grid__item {
  background-color: #BDBDBD;
}

.grid__item--1 {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}

.grid__item--5 {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--1">1</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--2">2</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--3">3</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--4">4</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--5">5</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--6">6</div>
</div>
```

При этом получается такой результат
[image: example result]

**Почему пятый блок становится перед вторым?**

Код: https://jsfiddle.net/serhioses/51do02xa/

Comment: Интересный вопрос, никак не могу найти почему так. Хотя если задать вместо `1 / -1` `span 2` все работает так надо. Но, это не неявные гриды.

Comment: Ответ есть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924156/220571). Если вкратце то блоки, у которых явно заданы ячейки располагаются первыми (к примеру, через свойство `grid-row`), затем идут все остальные автоматически.