# Почему из за `grid-row: 1 / -1` грид элементы размещаются начиная с первой колонки?

Tags: css, css3, css-grid

Почему `второй` и `третий` элеметы со свойством `grid-row: 1 / -1` размещаются начиная с первой колонки? Но, если задать сколько полос должен занимать элемент `grid-row: span 2` (пятый блок), то он остается на своем месте.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  padding: 5rem;
  grid-template-rows: [start1] 100px [end1 start2] 100px  [end2] 50px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  //grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}
.grid__item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.grid__item-2 {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}
.grid__item-3 {
  grid-row-start: start1;
  grid-row-end: end2;
}
.grid__item-5 {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item grid__item-1">1</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item-2">2</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item-3">3</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item-4">4</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item-5">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-placement-algo), это дефолтное поведение. Алгоритм авто размещения `grid-элементов` у которых определенно свойство `grid-row-start/end` задает стартовую линию колонки с наименьшим положительным индексом. Что бы избежать перекрытие данной области `grid-area` и занятием другой `grid-cell`.

> Process the items locked to a given row.
>
> For each grid item with a definite row position (that is, the grid-row-start and grid-row-end properties define a definite grid position), in order-modified document order:
>
> “sparse” packing (default behavior)
>
> Set the column-start line of its placement to the earliest (smallest positive index) line index that ensures this item’s grid area will not overlap any occupied grid cells and that is past any grid items previously placed in this row by this step.

Насколько я понял, `пятый` блок размещается на своем месте из за того, что мы не указываем `grid-линии` к которым он должен быть привязан, а просто задаем ему размер в 2 `grid-полосы`.